# Need help to type function output based on function inputs in typescript

Tags: typescript

I need help to figure out how to type function output based on it's input value. I almost did it, but somehow I am missing something and I can't figure out what exactly.

I want to achieve compile time type recognition/autocompletion like this:

`const { A: { B, C, D} } = foo( {A: ["B","C","D"] }`

As  you can see I am passing `B,C and D` as strings and I want them to be used as keys(attached with some array of strings) in response's nested objects.

I did something like this:

`const foo = <T extends Record<string, Array<string>>,>(x: T) : Record<keyof T, Record<T[keyof T][number], Array<string>>> => { ..... }`

But unfortunately I am getting just autocompletion for the first level, meaning I can see that typescript recognizes that `A` is presented as root key in response object, but I can't get typescript to recognize `B,C and D` as nested sub objects.

Comment: Dummy generic parameter: https://tsplay.dev/Nd2dXW

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NrDGlW) meet your needs? I wish I knew what type you expected `B`, `C`, and `D` to be in the output, but I suppose it's arbitrary.  Anyway if that meets your needs I will write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (Pls mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks to both of you! Both solutions works perfectly fine, I will study them a bit more detailed!